# How to modify iteration list?

Tags: python, list, iteration, os.walk

Following scenario of traversing dir structure.

"Build complete dir tree with files but if files in single dir are similar in name list only single entity"

Example tree ( let's assume they're are not sorted ):

```
    - rootDir
        -dirA
            fileA_01
            fileA_03
            fileA_05
            fileA_06
            fileA_04
            fileA_02
            fileA_...
            fileAB
            fileAC
        -dirB
            fileBA
            fileBB
            fileBC
```

Expected output:

```
    - rootDir
        -dirA
            fileA_01 - fileA_06 ...
            fileAB
            fileAC
        -dirB
            fileBA
            fileBB
            fileBC
```

So I did already simple `def findSimilarNames`  that for `fileA_01` (or any `fileA_`) will return list [`fileA_01`...`fileA_06`]

Now I'm in `os.walk` and I'm doing loop over files so every file will be checked against similar filenames so e.g `fileA_03` I've got rest of them [`fileA_01` - `fileA_06`] and now I want to modify the list that I iterate over to just skip items from `findSimilarNames`, without need of using another loop or `if`'s inside.

I searched here and people are suggesting avoidance of modifying iteration list, but doing so I would avoid every file iteration.

Pseudo code:

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk( path ):
    for file in files:
        similarList = findSimilarNames( file )

        #OVERWRITE ITERATION LIST SOMEHOW
        files = (set(files)-set(similarList))

        #DEAL WITH ELEMENT
```

What I'm trying to avoid is below - checking each file because maybe it's already found by `findSimilarNames`.

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk( path ):
    filteredbysimilar = files[:]
    for file in files:
        similar = findSimilarNames( file )
        filteredbysimilar = list(set(filteredbysimilar)-set(similar))
    #--
    for filteredFile in filteredbysimilar:
        #DEAL WITH ELEMENT
```

Comment: When you say similar filenames, you mean files that have the same prefix that precedes an underscore?

Comment: just use `continue` if file is in `similar`. Have to say, it is not very clear what you want... You can't *change* the iteration when using `for`. The `for` loop runs on an iterator and each iteration will take the next element even if you play for the loop's variable

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, but it doesn't need to be underscore and it's not the case here, filenames could be e.g `filename.secondPart.1234.0001 - filename.secondPart.1234.0100`

Comment: @Tomerikoo THX. but by using continue I'm looping over each file anyway and doing check `if file in similar` ... or maybe I misunderstood your answer

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. But I believe that it is necessary as how you are going to know if you need to skip a file, if you don't even go over the file (and aware of its existence). See my point?

Comment: Sure ... I got your point but also as I said `findSimilarNames` would give me that aware of its existence. Imagine your directory contains file sequence e.g `file_0001 - file_9999` by iterating first element e.g `file_0456` I already know that i don't need to iterate further, because files from `file_0001` to `file_9999` are similar. Thanks again for intrest.

Answer (score 1):

> `#OVERWRITE ITERATION LIST SOMEHOW`

You can get this effect by using a while-loop style iteration. Since you want to do set subtraction to remove the similar groups anyway, the natural approach is to start with a set of all the filenames, and repeatedly remove groups until nothing is left. Thus:

```
unprocessed = set(files)
while unprocessed:
    f = unprocessed.pop() # removes and returns an arbitrary element
    group = findSimilarNames(f)
    unprocessed -= group # it is not an error that `f` has already been removed.
    doSomethingWith(group) # i.e., "DEAL WITH ELEMENT" :)
```

Comment: THX. Seems that `while` would work best here. But out of curiosity, and learnig purposes - is it possible at all to do it in for loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about building up a list of files that aren't similar?

```
unsimilar = set()
for f in files:
    if len(findSimilarNames(f).intersection(unsimilar))==0:
        unsimilar.add(f)
```

This assumes `findSimilarNames` yields a set.

Comment: It is more Pythonic to check for an empty sequence with `if not sequence:` rather than asking for its `len` explicitly. I know, the Zen says to be explicit, but that's just the standard idiom. The difference between "explicit" and "complex" is subtle, I guess :)

Comment: @ScottHunter THX. But searching for unsimilar doesn't mean that I don't need to iterate over all files .... or not ?

Comment: You *are* iterating over all files: to decide which to add.  You never add a file that is similar to one you have already decided is unique enough.